# Bind ViewModel to XAML View in Prism.Forms

Tags: forms, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, prism

In Xamarin.Forms it is possible to specify the `ViewModel` to be used with a XAML page within the markup via the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag. The only advantage to doing this that I can see - vs. Prism.Forms' much more flexible ways of tying Views to `ViewModel`s - is that then I get *IntelliSense* in the XAML about the VM properties/commands when adding my `{Binding}` attribute values.

Again, Prism.Forms has better ways to bind views and `ViewModel`s, but when I use them, I usually don't get the *IntelliSense* in the XAML page - which would actually be quite helpful with a complex View/ViewModel.

I don't see any reason that I can't use the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag in Prism.Forms scenarios. But that feels like I am "breaking" the way that Prism wants to do `View`-to-`ViewModel` bindings.

Also, I am worried that my `ViewModel` will be instantiated twice unnecessarily, once when Xamarin.Forms creates it; and once when Prism does its binding.  Not sure if that is correct...  Also, I can see a scenario where I want to bind my view to different `ViewModel`s at various times; a different VM class for Android vs. iOS, for example. Prism lets me do that, but I am worried that wouldn't work with the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag present.

Is there a supported/recommended way to identify my `ViewModel` in my XAML for design-time purposes only (i.e. for intellisense) but have Prism's view-to-viewmodel binding logic happen at run-time?  I think I want the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag to be completely ignored except while I am editing the XAML in Visual Studio.

EDIT: My question above was incorrect in that the XAML View *IntelliSense* that I was expecting to see is not provided by Visual Studio, but by JetBrains *ReSharper*. The solution described below **did** add back the expected *IntelliSense* functionality, but only in a development environment where *ReSharper* was installed (or there may be other Visual Studio add-ins with this feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan's answer below was helpful, but a better solution has been described by Atsushi Nakamura - here: [Enable IntelliSense for ViewModel members with Prism for Xamarin.Forms blog](https://blog.nuits.jp/enable-intellisense-for-viewmodel-members-with-prism-for-xamarin-forms-2f274e7c6fb6)

Essentially, his approach is to (1) create a fake "design-time" service locator for view models - that returns null for each ViewModel type; and then (2) reference this service locator in XAML views as a static binding for the page's BindingContext. This provides the *IntelliSense* during design-time (when ReSharper or a similar Visual Studio add-in is present); but at run-time the service locator returns null, and Prism performs its typical View-to-ViewModel binding.

Based on the discussion on an issue that was created on the Prism repository on GitHub, the approach mentioned above will be added to the official Prism for Xamarin.Forms docs as the recommended way to provide design time data. See that discussion here: [related Prism GitHub issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/986)

So that resolved my problem and added back the design-time *IntelliSense* that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't say I have heard of any consensus about how to best handle this issue, I can at least give you an answer. The tooling from Microsoft/Xamarin is still very new as far as being a stable release, and unfortunately out of the box it does not seem to support dynamically loading in ViewModels. I've gone ahead and created an issue on GitHub for Prism that you can follow [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/986).

In the mean time if you need to make the binding more strongly typed so that the Xamarin Forms Previewer can find the ViewModel then I would suggest setting `AutoWire=false` so Prism does not create the ViewModel a second time.

As painful as it is to admit, sometimes being on the cutting edge (which the Xaml Previewer still is), means making sacrifices and having to break rules and patterns to make things work. Hope that helps.

Comment: At this moment, I am not looking for Xamarin XAML Previewer support, just Intellisense about the properties on my viewmodels.  So, I think you have a good suggestion - use the Xamarin.Forms "viewmodel binding" technique (using ContentPage.BindingContext) and then set AutoWire=false.  I guess my only worry about that approach is that the Prism/Unity based constructor injection on my viewmodels won't work (since X.F is creating the VM instance, instead of Prism).  I can give that a try myself, but just wondering if anyone has any warnings for me about not using Prism View-to-ViewModel binding.

Comment: The environment currently has no direct tooling to support linking the View and ViewModel. Thus neither the IntelliSense nor the Previewer can really use them. That said, the issue created was due to the fact that no real work could begin on it until the previewer was finished, hence the issue posted. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate your help and info.  Just to respond to my own comment:  Using the ContentPage.BindingContext tag in my XAML views is a no-go, because then it wants my ViewModel class to have a parameter-less constructor; and that gets called when the ViewModel instance is created vs. my Prism-enabled constructor with injectables like INavigationService, etc.  So, that is a deal-breaker and I can't use the ContentPage.BindingContext tag.  I wish there was some way to make that tag only be respected by VStudio and not at compile/run time. Like some notation in the XAML or something.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dansiegel/226a26bb528baed4e18dcc9d5554b665) you can use. I want to be clear I'm not saying this is a great strategy. However, I believe it may provide you a hack to accomplish your goal.